# How to isolate .Net websites running in FullTrust

Tags: asp.net, security, cas

In a scenario where an IIS server is running multiple websites, what is the current best practices to protect each website from each other?

The objective is that website A should not have access to any resources from website B

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done by using one common computer account that is the one that be able to run the pages, and one user account per site that be able to read the resource only for the associate site.

So each site have the common computer account that can be able to run it and its connected to the pool, is the one that computer manage and runs.

And one personal account different for each site. When a user connected to the site, the iis is assign this isolate account, but when the computer runs it is use the common computer account.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I would run them with different process accounts and use acls to restrict access to each other files, including system files etc. this would be considered fairly standard practice.

Obviously this requires separate application pools.